# Can I perform incremental backups with Syncthing?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, snapshot, syncthing

I have found [a page](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Using-rsync-for-Backups) which describes how to go about doing incremental backups using `rysnc`. To me incremental backups are good not only because they save space and time but also because you can potentially manage a snapshot system, like `Timeshift`, where for any one of several reasons, including synched deletion of files that were not meant to be deleted, you have the possibility of going "back in time".

`Timeshift` itself appears to use `rsync`. As far as I can work out you can't configure `Timeshift` to sync any arbitrary location, or apply filters: it's either "my system" or "my system plus my home directory".

Also, again as I understand it, `rsync` (and thus `Timeshift`) has the potential limitation that it is "brute force": to determine changes between systems it must "walk" the entire file structures of both source and destination.

`Syncthing`, on the other hand, combines such "brute force" scanning with the ability to respond to file system events, although it says [here](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/syncing.html) that the ability to respond (to a file creation, deletion or modification, I presume) is not 100% foolproof. Nevertheless, that means you could set your "full scan" to a fairly infrequent interval, say each hour, but still hope to see synching happening faster.

Is it possible to implement such a `Timeshift`-like "structured snapshot" arrangement using `Syncthing`?

Comment: Why not use backup software for doing backups? `borgbackup` and `restic` works well even on very large sets of files.  Alternatively, use a filesystem that supports taking snapshots, like ZFS.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the most important part of a backup scheme: Restoring. Will you have to restore the full backup plus all the incrementals, or will your incremental  backup grow constantly? This will let you restore the Full plus any ONE incremental (to go back in time). Will the size of the Incremental (backup since the last Full) contribute to the decision to run a Full?

Comment: @they I discovered restic about a year ago. It has totally transformed my backup life and means that I don't have to look for, or devote time to thinking about, any other backup solutions ever again!

Comment: **rsnapshot**  ?